# Утопающий в зелени сад

Tags: грамотная-речь

> Утопающий в зелени сад

Можно ли так писать? В Нацкорпусе не нашел, но Гугл дает 2180 результатов. Но все же, не скрыта ли здесь тавтология? Ведь пишут "в зелени сада". Значит сад утопает в собственной зелени? Или сад можно представить как некое пространство, утопающее в зелени деревьев?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не нахожу здесь тавтологии: поскольку "вечнозелёные" сады - редкость, такое выражение *информативно*, например, в отношении времени года и даже (на примере состояния сада) может указывать на период *буйного* развития растительности в местности с определённым климатом. Иными словами, здесь акцент на том, что сад "буйно зеленеет" (буквально утопая в собственной зелени). У выражения же "в зелени сада" другая функция: оно чаще обозначает место действия или фон (сад с его растительностью), на котором рассматривается что-то другое.

Answer (score 3):

Утопающий в зелени сад — это метафора, которая уже воспринимается как устойчивое выражение. В ее основе  глаголы  утонуть/утопать, которые передают идею избыточности. В данном случае это большое количество зелени, которая закрывает всё видимое   пространство.

Речь идет о густом, разросшемся саде, так как сады бывают разные (регулярные, пейзажные и др. http://www.ldgrand.ru/stati/vidyi-sadov)

УТОПАТЬ, нсв. 1. Разг. =Тонуть. У. в пруду. 2. в чём. **Пользоваться чем-л. в излишестве, отдаваться, предаваться чему-л. сверх меры, нормы.** У. в роскоши, в богатстве. У. в довольстве, в блаженстве. У. в работе. ◊ Утопать в крови (см. Кровь). Утопать в слезах. Проливать много слёз.

САД, м. 1. Участок земли для выращивания садовых растений, **садовые растения** (цветы, фруктовые деревья и кустарники), произрастающие на таком участке. Выделить землю под сады и огороды. Купить домик с садом. **Посадить сад.** Сады цветут. Фруктовый сад. Вишнёвый сад. Зимний сад.